# Recreating sentence in python: List index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to write recreate a senetence using the words that make up the sentence and the positiosn of words. When I run my code I get the error 'List index out of range'. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks :). All of my code is below.

```
        def compress():     #function that will compress the inputted sentence/sentences

    sentence = input("Input the sentence that you wish to be compressed") #Sentence to be compressed
    sentence.lower()#Puts sentence in lower-case
    sentencelist = sentence.split() #Splits the sentence into a list
    d = {} #Dictionary

    plist = [] #List that contains the positions of the words
    wds = []
    for i in sentencelist: #iterating through the inputted sentence
        if i not in wds: #if item not in list of words...
            wds.append(i) #...append to the list of words
    for i ,j in enumerate(sentencelist):#Enumerates the sentence and gets the positions
        if j in (d): #if the item (j) is in the d 
            plist.append(d[j]) #append the item to the list of positions
        else:
            d[j] =i             #else, append item (i) to position list
            plist.append(i)     #appends to the list of positions 
    print (plist) #print the list containing the positions. 


    with open ("tsk3pos.txt", "wt") as txt: #opens the file

        position_string = " ".join(str(x) for x in plist)   #makes/recreates sentence using positons and words
        txt.write(position_string)

        txt.close()                     #closes the file
        with open ("tsk3wds.txt", "wt") as txt: #opens the file

            for item in wds:            #iterates through list of words 
                txt.write("%s\n" % item)    #puts lists in the file
        txt.close() #closes the file


    print (wds) #prints list that contains words that are in the sentence
    main()  #calls main function



def recreate(compress): #function that will be used to recreate the compressed sentence.

    num = []    #creates list for positions (blank)
    wds = []    #creates list for words (blank)

    with open("words.txt", "r") as txt: #with statement opening the word text file
        for line in txt: #iterating over each line in the text file.
            wds += line.split() #turning the textfile into a list and appending it to num

    with open("tsk3pos.txt", "r") as txt:   #opens text file with list of positions in read code
        for line in txt:                    #iterates through
            num += [int(i) for i in line.split()]    #turns the textfile into list and appends to blank list


    recreate = ' '.join(wds[pos] for pos in num)    #makes/recreates sentence using positons and words

    with open("recreate.txt", "wt") as txt: #opens recreate text file in write mode
        txt.write(recreate)                 #writes sentences to 'recreate' text file

    main()                                  #calls the  main function



def main():                                 #defines main function
    print("Do you want to compress an input or recreate a compressed input?") #user input 
    user = input("Type 'a' if you want to compress an input. Type 'b' if you wan to recreate an input").lower() #gives user choice ad puts input in lower case
    if user not in ("a","b"):                   #if input isn't a or b...
        print ("That's not an option. Please try again")    #give error message
    elif user == "a":           #if input is a...
        compress()              #...call the compress function
    elif user == "b":           #if input is b...
        recreate(compress)      #...call recreate function with compress as argument
    main()                      #calls main function

main()                          #Calls main function
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?  Show us the stack trace ;-)

Comment: @Alfe Thanks for replying. I get errors on lines 74, 72, 69, 36, 71 and 54.

Comment: Please provide the details of all the errors.

Comment: @Matthew Cliatt The error given is 'IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You just said you get errors on line 74, 72, 69, 36, and 54. Are they all the same exact error?

Comment: @Matthew Cliatt Yes, they are all the same error

Comment: How do you get more than one runtime error? The program stops after one occurs.

Comment: @Matthew Cliatt All of the errors are part of one large error

Comment: Please post the complete traceback here. It should look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace). Giving us the line numbers where the errors occur makes it inconvenient for us to count.

Comment: @Reti43 The whole traceback is too long but I will post some of the tracebacks.

Comment: @Reti43  File "E:\code\Task 3_6.py", line 54, in recreate
    recreate = ' '.join(wds[pos] for pos in num)        #makes/recreates sentence using positons and words
  File "E:\code\Task 3_6.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    recreate = ' '.join(wds[pos] for pos in num)        #makes/recreates sentence using positons and words
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two errors:

1) In your recreate function you look for a file words.txt when in your compress function you write the words to tsk3wds.txt

2) In lines 17-18 you are saving the index of the word in the uncompressed sentence when you actually need the index of that word in list wds. You can change those two lines to this and will most likely work:

```
index = [index for index, x in enumerate(wds) if x == j][0]
d[j] = index
plist.append(index)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I put this into my code, it returned an answer and said that index was not defined.                                             Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\code\Task 3_8.py", line 18, in <module>
    d[j] = index
NameError: name 'index' is not defined
>>>

Comment: We are just defining index here so it should be defined. Maybe an indentation error. Are those 3 lines inside that else statement?

Comment: This is the else statement:else:
   index = [index for index, x in enumerate(wds) if x == j][0]
   d[j] = index
   plist.append(index)                                                             It now says that plist is not defined

Comment: It should be working but for some reason it isn't working.

Comment: I edited the code directly in your question can you try that and copy/paste as it is?

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much! You are a life saver! XD